# Debugging C++ on SublimeText

Tags: c++, debugging, sublimetext

Following https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Debugger to debug python in ST, I noticed .sublime-project gets an additional section

```
"debugger_configurations":
[
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}"
    },
],
```

I tried to do something similar for a simple C++ project in ST. Then I saw

```
"debugger_configurations":
[
    {
        "type": "gdb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "target": "./bin/executable",
        "cwd": "${folder}",
        "valuesFormatting": "parseText"
    },
],
```

I set a breakpoint and hit play, which led to

```
Could not start debugger process, does the program exist in filesystem?
Error: spawn gdb ENOENT
Debugging ended
```

I changed `"target": "./myexecutable"`, hit play again and got the same result as before.

Is it possible to debug C++ on ST? I wondering where I'm going wrong.

2nd try, with lldb it adds:

```
"debugger_configurations":
[
    {
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch",
        "program": "${folder}/<program>",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${folder}"
    },
```

Hit play and

Console is in 'commands' mode, prefix expressions with '?'.
unable to find executable for '/Users/user/project/'

[image]

Then changed "program": "${folder}/${file_base_name}",

and got

[image]

Comment: Do you have gdb?

Comment: Have you installed gdb? Is it available on your path?

Comment: Well no. Tried brew install gdb and it failed, on macOS M1. Tried lldb then, going to update the question.

Comment: Wrong name of program.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/daveleroy/SublimeDebugger/blob/master/examples/cpp/cpp.sublime-project

```
"debugger_configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ (Console)",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${project_path}",
        "cwd": "${project_path}",
        "terminal": "external",
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a [bug](https://github.com/daveleroy/SublimeDebugger/issues/215) with the debugger plugin itself. It has been fixed in a [recent commit](https://github.com/daveleroy/SublimeDebugger/commit/f07ac3607e68e0c1782009481fed642dad18a8bf).

The plugin on package control is outdated and has not been updated by the developer in a while, and some of the recent patches are unavailable there. Install the plugin by directly cloning SublimeDebugger's [github repository](https://github.com/daveleroy/SublimeDebugger) into your packages folder (found inside Sublime Text's [data directory](https://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/basic_concepts.html#the-data-directory)) should fix your issue.

If that still does not work, try checking out an older commit using git. The current version might be a bit unstable <sup>[citation needed]</sup>